# jQuery button click function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I want to show div on button click. SO for that I have written code like below

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDownloadExcelTemp" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-blue" Text="Download Template" OnClick="btnDownloadExcelTemp_Click" OnClientClick="return showHideUploadDiv();" />
```

Div which I want to enable

```
<div class="col-md-9" id="dvUploadFile" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    Upload file
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <asp:FileUpload ID="fluploadData" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">

        <asp:Button ID="btnUploadExcelData" CssClass="btn btn-blue" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUploadExcelData_Click" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

But while calling the function which is below, the div is not getting showed.

```
function showHideUploadDiv() {            
  alert('1');
  $("#MainContent_btnDownloadExcelTemp").click(function () {
    $('#dvUploadFile').show();
  });
}
```

**Note:** The alert is firing but it is not getting inside the function. Please suggest why it's happening like this.

Comment: Your function sets up an event handler but it doesn't actually *call* the handler.

Comment: @Pointy: ohh, but how come the alert is firing ? any other way to do this ?

Comment: The `alert()` is *outside* the event handler.

Comment: @Pointy: yes, so is it achievable ?

Comment: Also, if you use .show(), then you should consider using .hide() before and not putting the element to "display:none" before. Although it affects the display property, it may not it alter it the way you want, the doc says "This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block" ), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially." so basically in your case it may put it back to display:none and thus never show it. So if you use display:none, you're better off using .css("display","block") instead of .show()

Comment: According to the doc, your code should work, so put an alert Inside the event Handler, to know where the problem is really located. On your Handler or your show function.

Comment: @ZakariaSahmane no, the code should not work. The `showHideUploadDiv()` function is already bound as a "click" handler for the button.

Comment: @ZakariaSahmane: I already tried that and it was not working. that's the reason why I posted here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the code adding your .click function, so it is like this?:

```
function showHideUploadDiv() {            
    alert('1');
    $('#dvUploadFile').css("display", "block");
}
```

You do not need to assign an onclick to the button inside your function as your function is already assigned to the button in this line:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDownloadExcelTemp" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-blue" Text="Download Template" OnClick="btnDownloadExcelTemp_Click" OnClientClick="return showHideUploadDiv();" />

// "OnClientClick="return showHideUploadDiv();"
```

Comment: its working perfectly fine..one more thing, how can we hide it on page load ?

Comment: you already are? setting the div's style="display: none;" property.
Which is also why I changed your ".show();" to ".css("display", "block")". As  Zakaria Sahmane commented on your question; If you want to show it using .show();, you should also use .hide(); to hide it. But using the .css changes is just as ok for hiding and showing.

Comment: no but I did it..thanks Magnus..it was simple and perfectly answered :)